# How to Bind dynamic Data of objects in vb .net or on .aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, aspxgridview

I have a Table of Subject Marks and it is dynamic , I want to bind this data on my .aspx page and also want to save or edit these data into database from the page .

Table : SubjectMarks

Subject  Marks
English   70
Math      80
Science   90
History   60

I want to save on the page like :

English
70 will be in textbox here

Math
80

Science
90

History
60

I can change the marks data from the textboxes and save the update ones into databse.

Please help me to find this stuff in asp.net. I have .aspx page and backend in .vb

Comment: Please include snippets showing your progress thus far and details as to what's been attempted. The community loves to answer specific questions within your work but unlikely to provide the solution for you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there are MANY ways to do this.

And you can even use/get the wizards to wire up editing for you. However, I find the built in template editing system REALLY messy to work with.

Having come from desktop land (VB6, ms-access, foxpro), then I want to NOT have to write whacks of code, and I want mostly a drag + drop like easy experience.

So, how to edit some marks for a student that is taking some classes?

Well, I would assume in our database we have Students and StudentCourse table.

(lets keep this simple!)

So, say we have this:

[image]

Ok, so we need a combo box to select a student, and then display their courses.

So, first would be say a simple combo box (dropdown) to select a student.

Then we could display the courses, and let you edit the marks. And then an easy save button to save our edits.

Ok, so lets drop in the drop down (combo box). To select the student, and then drop in a gridview for the courses (for display and edit).

And then let’s drop in a button (for saving the edits).

In fact, in place of gridview, lets use a listview. They are VERY similar, but I like listview more since it allows use of standard controls being dropped into the grid display with LESS mess then the gridview. (but, either choice works – I just like the listview better. And it has FAR more customizing abilities. So time spent learning the lv is well worth it.

So, we have this simple markup:

```
<div style="margin:20px">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Select Student: " Font-Size="Large"></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="cboStudents" runat="server" Style="font-size:large;width:180px;margin-left:5px" 
        AutoPostBack="true"
        DataTextField = "FullName"
        DataValueField ="ID">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div  style="width:25%;border:solid;border-width:thin">
        <style>  input {border:none}</style>
        <asp:ListView ID="LstMarks" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td><asp:Textbox ID="Course" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Course") %>' /></td>
                    <td><asp:Textbox ID="Mark" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Mark") %>' Width="30px"/></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="DoneLabs" runat="server" Checked = '<%# Eval("DoneLabs") %>' Width="30px"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" class="table">
                    <tr runat="server" style="">
                        <th runat="server" >Course</th>
                        <th runat="server">Mark</th>
                        <th runat="server" >Completed Lab Work</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </div>

    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="cmdSave" runat="server" Text="Save" class="btn"/>
    <asp:Button ID="cmdAdd" runat="server" Text="Add Course" class="btn" Style="margin-left:20px" />
    <asp:Button ID="cmdUndo" runat="server" Text="Undo Edits" class="btn" Style="margin-left:20px" />
</div>
```

Ok, so lets write code to fill up that combo box.

In Project Settings, we add the database connection string here:

(it puts in in web config for you - but this way is OH so much easy - and you get to use the connection string builder).

[image]

Ok, so now lets write code to load up the combo box

we have this:

```
Dim rstMarks As New DataTable
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        cboStudents.DataSource =
            MyRst("SELECT *, FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS FullName from Students ORDER BY FirstName")
        cboStudents.DataBind()
        cboStudents.Items.Insert(0, "")
    Else
        rstMarks = ViewState("MyMarks")
    End If

End Sub
```

So in above, we load up our combo box, and we ALSO have a table for the marks table (and we persisted the rstMarks table - since we need it for editing).

Ok, so we select a student, and fill the list view.

That code looks like this:

```
Protected Sub cboStudents_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboStudents.SelectedIndexChanged

    LoadMarks()

End Sub

Sub LoadMarks()

    Dim strSQL As String
    strSQL = "SELECT * from StudentCourses WHERE Student_ID = " & cboStudents.SelectedValue &
             " ORDER BY Course"
    rstMarks = MyRst(strSQL)
    LstMarks.DataSource = rstMarks
    LstMarks.DataBind()

    ViewState("MyMarks") = rstMarks

End Sub
```

Our output is now this:

[image]

So you can now tab around, set the course name, mark, and I tossed in for fun a check box for having completed "lab" work.

So, now we need our save button code. After the user tabs around, edits any mark, or changes a check box, we have to send the edits back to the database.

That code looks like this:

```
Protected Sub cmdSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSave.Click

    GridToTable()
    SaveToDB()

End Sub

Sub GridToTable()

    ' move grid edits back to table.
    For Each gRow As ListViewItem In LstMarks.Items

        Dim OneRow As DataRow = rstMarks.Rows(gRow.DataItemIndex)
        OneRow("Course") = CType(gRow.FindControl("Course"), TextBox).Text
        OneRow("Mark") = CType(gRow.FindControl("Mark"), TextBox).Text
        OneRow("DoneLabs") = CType(gRow.FindControl("DoneLabs"), CheckBox).Checked

    Next

End Sub

Sub SaveToDB()

    Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM StudentCourses WHERE ID = 0",
                    New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4))
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL)
        Dim daSQL As New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
        da.Update(rstMarks)
    End Using

End Sub
```

So what the above does? It moves grid values back to the table.

THEN Sends the data table (with edits, or even new rows added) back to the database.

And that is quite much it.

I tossed in a add course button, and code for that is this:

```
Protected Sub cmdAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdAdd.Click

    GridToTable()         ' user might have made edits - send them to table
    ' add a new row to table
    Dim OneRow As DataRow = rstMarks.NewRow
    OneRow("Student_ID") = cboStudents.SelectedItem.Value
    OneRow("DoneLabs") = False
    OneRow("Mark") = 0

    rstMarks.Rows.Add(OneRow)
    LstMarks.DataSource = rstMarks     ' send table to grid
    LstMarks.DataBind()

End Sub
```

And I did create a helper routine to get data into a table, and that code was:

```
Function MyRst(strSQL As String) As DataTable

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4))
        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
        rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
    End Using

    Return rstData

End Function
```

And the un-do edits button? It just re-loads the grid without saving, and thus is this:

```
Protected Sub cmdUndo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdUndo.Click

    LoadMarks()

End Sub
```

(it just does the SAME thing as selecting a student in the combo box.

So, the above is FULL of great ideas on how to do this.

And really, it not a lot of code, and you can quite much use the above approach for just about any kind of data editing you need.